# why default Xcode project settings won't recognise __cplusplus block

Tags: objective-c, xcode, c++11

Hi I encounter this strange problem with Xcode7, here is what I did:

create a new project, add a .pch file, and in build settings set the .pch file as precompile prefix file.

Added

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <somefile.hpp>
#else
#import <somefile.hpp>
#endif
```

in the .pch file to test whether xcode will go __cplusplus block or not, and here is screenshot of result:

[image]

You can see that it did not go to `__cpluscplus` block.

Anyone knows what I should do to make it recognise `__cplusplus` block?

Comment: Is the compilation unit that's producing this error a `.m` or `.mm` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix header will be built for every language you use.

For some files (.c, .m), it will go through the `#ifdef __cplusplus`part, for others (.cpp, .mm) it will not.

In most Xcode templates, you will have main.m / main.c file that will cause the `#else` part to be compiled.
If you add c++ / ObjC++ source files to the project, they will use a pch built with `__cplusplus` being defined.